# Media Queries for Pixel ratio not working

Tags: ios, css, media, media-queries

im trying to put retina background images in certain elements and im having trouble actually getting these media queries to work. Sublime text wont syntax highlight them either so im pretty sure this stack is broken but i have no idea what to do. Help pelase?

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (   -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one pixel ration should be applied for it to work. Think about it, when the -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio will be 1.5, it will not be for -o-min-device-pixel-ratio. We only have "and" rules. If all of the rules are not true at once, the condition will not be applied.

Try this code:

```
only screen and ( min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5 ){ 
}
```

For other rules, apply them separately for everytime. That will cause your CSS code to be lengthy but its the only solution for now.

Comment: That's wrong, from W3C specs : " If one or more of the media queries in the comma-separated list are true, the whole list is true, and otherwise false. In the media queries syntax, the comma expresses a logical OR, while the ‘and’ keyword expresses a logical AND."